# How to specify the context for an EJB in JBOSS

Tags: jboss, ejb

I've got some legacy code that runs in JBoss which looks something like:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(MyClass.class)
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "app/Service")
public class myServiceBean {
  // Some methods
}
```

When I look up the Bean in JNDI I have to use a string that looks like:

```
ear-name/Service/remote
```

I'm OK with the last two parts of the name, but I have an issue with *"ear-file"* being used as the context name. Because I build with Maven by default *ear-file* will contain the version number (which I do want for traceability), however it means I would have to change all the references to the service each time I issue a new version of the service!

How do I force the the context to something other than the name of the ear-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your ear name in application.xml like this:

```
<application-name>ear-name</application-name>
```

So you can have ear-namexxx.ear but your lookups will be made to ear-name

You can do the same for ejb modules as well:

```
<ejb-jar>  
  <module-name>ejb-name</module-name>
</ejb-jar>
```

Hope it helps!

Source https://developer.jboss.org/thread/158207

Comment: Thanks. :-)
Should anybody else want to know about this, I also needed to update the maven-ear-plugin and force it to use version 6 to generate the application.xml for version 6 before the <application-name> element was written